# .NET WPF framework foreach loop using checkboxes

Tags: c#, foreach, wpf-controls

I'm trying to sum up the total price of a service that is dependent on the number of checkboxes that are clicked on my form in WPF.

So if i have 1 checkbox that associates price with 10$ and another with 20$. If both checkboxes are checked, how would i sum up the total price to 30$?

This is the code i have so far, when i run the program, it only adds 1 of the checkboxes. Having trouble understanding what im doing wrong. Thanks in advance for the input.

```
foreach (CheckBox c in servicesGroupBox.Controls)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            if (c.Checked == true)
            {
                serviceRate = temp + serviceRate;
                temp = serviceRate;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Look into variable scope. Also how do you know which checkbox is the $10 or the $20? Side note, I would also look into `mvvm`  as well, it would make things like this very easy to do.

Comment: Since my checkboxes are a WPF control, im calling on its function to set the serviceRate price depending on which checkboxes are selected on the form. I'll look into variable scoping, hopefully that fixes it, thank you